# How to accept "enter" value?

Tags: php, forms, textarea, newline

I am using php5. I am doing a form, a textarea, where user can send it to his/her friends. But currently, in my textarea form, if i type :

> Hello XXX,
>
> Its been a while. How are you?

But when I echo it, it displays

> Hello XXX, Its been a while. How are
>   you?

How do I accept the enter button, so that when I display I can display like:

> Hello XXX,
>
> Its been a while. How are you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a function called [nl2br()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) which converts newlines `\n` to html friendly line breaks. `<br>` or `<br />`

It's used like this

```
echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");
```

This will output

```
foo isn't<br />bar
```

Since HTML is markup based, you will need some markup to tell the browser that you want a linebreak.

The reason is that

```
<p><b>Hello <i>World</i></b></p>
```

Is the exact same thing as

```
<p>
<b>
Hello 
<i>
World
</i>
</b>
</p>
```

Comment: Just remember that you should probably do the `nl2br` stuff when displaying it, not when you save it. That way you won't have to remove all the <br> tags later if you decide to do something different. Or if the user are going to be able to for example edit the text again.

Comment: What if i save to database first, and then display it out? I use mysql_real_escape_string to store in database

Comment: Leave the data alone if you save. When you're printing it to the page then you use nl2br().

Comment: Thanks, it works. Didnt read Svish comment. It pointed out that issue already.